# How to fire an event on expo av useNativeControls, specifically the Close (X)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm replicating the functionality you'd find in netflix or any streaming app. When I hit the video thumbnail it opens the video fullscreen and landscape. <- This is working. When I navigate back from the video player, it resets the UI to protrait. That is working as well. My problem is, when I close the video with the (X), it exists fullscreen but it remains on that navigation view until I hit Back on the header. That seems rather unnecessary since there is nothing else to do there. I would prefer it if I could attach a `navigate.goBack()` to that (X) control so that it not only exits fullscreen, but also go back to the screen it came from

```
//This is how I get my rotation when the video player loads and how ti resets when the user leaves that screen. Not sure if you need this
useEffect(() => {

    navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
        ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT);
    });

    navigation.addListener("blur", () => {
        ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.DEFAULT);
    });

}, [navigation]);


<Video
    ref={videoRef}
    source={{ uri: `https://judopedia.wiki/assets/videos/${videodata.url}` }}
    resizeMode="contain"
    shouldPlay
    isLooping
    style={styles.video}
    useNativeControls
    //  This plays the video on fullscreen 
    onLoad={()=>{
        videoRef?.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer();
    }}
    //  This is what I am hoping to do while the video is on fullscreen (if it existed)
    onClose={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
    }}
/>
```

[image: Here's the X I am referring to.]

[image: And this is what happens when I click it now. I want it to go back to where it came from (origin screenshot not included)]

Here's the X I am referring to.

And this is what happens when I click it now. I want it to go back to where it came from (origin screenshot not included)

Answer (score 0):

Alright Well, I figure out a solution, that may or may not be the right one. So feel free to challenge it and if a better solution is posted I'll change my answer

Here's the whole component

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated } from 'react-native'
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Video} from 'expo-av';
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";

//I save a constructor for the Anumated value in a constant av
const av = new Animated.Value(0);
av.addListener(() => {return});

//Then I added a listener to that Animation which I named fullscreenchange
av.addListener("fullscreenchange", () => {});



const VideoPlayerComponent = ({route, navigation}) => {

  const videodata = route.params.data;

  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  //this observer function fires on every change of the event that 
  // I am listening for
  const onFullscreenUpdate = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    // comment this part out first until you find out which event order
    // you need to target. Once you find out, you can change that number
    // an uncomment it
    if (event.fullscreenUpdate === 3) {
      navigation.goBack();
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {

    //This stuff is what makes my video go landscape and back to portrait whenever it has focus or not
    navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT);
    });

    navigation.addListener("blur", () => {
      ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.DEFAULT);
    });

  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainplayerview}>
      <View style={styles.videoitems}>
        <Video
          ref={videoRef}
          source={{ uri: `https://judopedia.wiki/assets/videos/${videodata.url}` }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          shouldPlay
          isLooping
          style={styles.video}
          useNativeControls
          //This makes it go to full screen when it loads
          onLoad={()=>{
            videoRef?.current?.presentFullscreenPlayer();
            }
          }
          //And finally I'm passing that observer I made earlier (listeners) to watch for every screen update
          onFullscreenUpdate={onFullscreenUpdate}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default VideoPlayerComponent
```

Now, check out your console and notice you should have a series of Objects updating you with every status change of your video. For me, it gave me 4. And if you have the console open you can see these Objects register every time your video view status changes. Worth to note, it doesn't register if you pause it or raise the volume. If it did, this solution would be worthless. So, because it only registered:

1. Object 0 - When it went to Landscape
2. Object 1 - When it went to Fullscreen
   after I hit the X
3. Object 2 - When it went back to regular view
4. Object 3 - When it went back to portrait

This allows me to target that specific status and do something on that status. For me, it was the last step (Object 3)

I went back up to my observer function and targeted the number 3 event (really 4th), and told it to navigate back to where I came from. For you it could be anything you want it to do

```
if (event.fullscreenUpdate === 3) {
   navigation.goBack();
}
```

Hope it helps. So far, no bugs

[image]